# How to find out what data was stored on my storage last day?

Tags: windows-7

I was surfing the Internet and programming all day. In afternoon I noticed my hard drive has got red, i.e. has less than 10% free space, although I have not downloaded files. Now is evening outside, and within this time I've got 1.3 GB less space. I have no idea what happened, might be I have a virus.

I want at least find out what files these are. Is it possible to get list of files from last day?

Answer (score 0):

On the desktop click op [My computer]. You will get a window similar to this one:

[image]

Select the search window and click on 'date modified'

[image]

If you select today from the calendar it will fill the search field with `datemodified:‎11/‎4/‎2012`

Search :)